# SSRS: Report subscription ran on off-cycle schedule

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

SQL Server 2014

I have a shared schedule for quarterly reporting that is set to go out on the 1st day of Jan, April, July, and Oct. However, the report went out on August 1st. I checked the report server and confirmed that the schedule is not set to run for August but the actual schedule table shows that the report did run for August 1st. In the SQL Agent job history, there is only one run, which is for August 1st and it was executed by the service account. The subscription says the next run date is Oct 1st.

So, I am at a loss to understand why the report ran off schedule. The system appears to confirm that the report is scheduled correctly but the system seems to have ran it off schedule. Are there any other troubleshooting steps that I can follow for this?

**Update (screenshot):**

[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the schedule (or schedules).

Comment: @WolfgangKais I have updated my post to provide a screenshot of the schedule.

Comment: This schedule will not run on 1st of December as you stated in your original post, so I guess there's another schedule, that's why I wrote "or schedules".

Comment: @WolfgangKais Just to clarify, I said it ran on August 1st, not December 1st. I confirmed that the subscription is assigned to run on the quarterly schedule. Is there any other way to get the report to run automatically; is it a server error; or did a human run it?

Comment: Yes, you said that it ran on August 1st, but you also said that it is scheduled for December 1st. You said that the service account ran the job, so there might be a malicious other job that executed this job. Or someone played with the system clock. I don't believe that it's a bug, I think that you have an opponent.

Comment: @WolfgangKais Good catch! Sorry, I missed that and I have updated my questions. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @WolfgangKais Is it possible to capture the SQL Agent job GUID that sent the report e-mail? This will allow me to rule out the malicious job idea. I doubt that the job will still be set to run if I go over and ask now.

Comment: I would start determining the ScheduleID(s) of the subscription(s) for your report. Use the tables Catalog, Subscriptions and ReportSchedule from the ReportServer database.for this. These IDs are by default the names of the SQL Server Agent Jobs that run the subscriptions. If this doesn't help, try to find additional jobs that contain the ID of a subscription in a jobstep… try to query the dbo.sysjobsteps table in the msdb database.

Comment: And: also check the ExecutionLogStorage table in the ReportServer database to find the execution of August 1st. The details might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our discussion in the comments, I guess that someone had the idea to rename the original job for the subscription to a human-readable name and didn't tell you before he left the company. To find that job, you can of course go through the list of jobs of SQL Server Agent and see if you can find a job with a name that has something to do with your report/subscription. If this isn't enough, open the *Job Activity Monitor* in SSMS (under SQL Server Agent) and look for a job that was last executed on August 1st at the time the emails went out. If this isn't successful and there are too many jobs to go through manually, I suggest to do the following:

- Find the *ItemID* of your report in the *Catalog* table of the ReportServer database (use *Path* and *Name* to identify your report).
- Find the *SubscriptionID* of your subscription in the *Subscriptions* table of the ReportServer database, filtering the *Report_OID* column using the *ItemID* of the report.

Then, find this `<SubscriptionID>` in the steps of jobs for SQL Server Agent using a query like this in the **msdb** database:

```
SELECT j.[name] AS job_name, s.step_name
FROM dbo.sysjobs j
  INNER JOIN dbo.sysjobsteps s ON j.job_id = s.job_id
WHERE s.command like '%<SubscriptionID>%'
```

(Replace `<SubscriptionID>` by the *SubscriptionID* of your subscription).

I guess that you will find (at least) 2 jobs with this query, one with your quarterly schedule and one that is scheduled to run on August 1st, both with a jobstep command like `EXEC dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', @EventData='<SubscriptionID>'` executed in the ReportServer database (with your `<SubscriptionID>`). Do whatever is appropriate with that second job.

Comment: I tried the 2nd query but got zero results for the given SubscriptionID. I tried looking at the data a bit but the Ops support technician did not have much time for me and unfortunately I do not have even basic read permissions in production to confirm. Without permissions and support time, I am stuck. I will mark this as answered to acknowledge your efforts. Thank you.

Comment: @JWeezy Thank you very much, I hope that the privileged user finds some time to support you soon, and when he did, please let me know the results.